# How to post/delete data from form into database using Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I am using a form to post a record to my database in Django. The form looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <div>Field 1</div>
    <input/>
    <div>Field 2</div>
    <input/>
    ...
    <a id='save'>Save</a>
</form>
```

I am using an event listener to let me know when this Save link has been clicked. When it is clicked, I would like to store the fields as a record in the database.

Here is my JS:

```
const savebtn = document.querySelector('#save');
savebtn.addEventListener('click', showSelected);

function showSelected(e) {
    // post record to database here
    window.location.replace("/"); // redirect to home page
```

I am hoping to use some python to post this record like shown below:

```
e = Entry()
e.field1 = 1
e.field2 = 2
e.save()
```

But I don't know how I can access a python function within JS. I'm thinking maybe a template tag could work here but can't figure out how to use it. Ideally I wouldn't have to rewrite the form as the formatting is kind of specific, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an endpoint that will do the algorithm.

ie. some urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_save_view', my_save_view, ...),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
def my_save_view(request):
    e = Entry()
    e.field1 = 1
    e.field2 = 2
    e.save()
```

and in javascript just get/fetch that endpoint when you want to. You can pass any values to the view with either GET or POST method in a standard way if needed.